# "flashblock" for all firefox plugins?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, noscript

I have the Firefox extension Flashblock installed, and enjoy the fact that it blocks all Flash (and Silverlight) while still giving me an option to run the Flash content if I want to (e.g. for YouTube). Can I get similar functionality for *all* plugins, such as QuickTime and Java? I've given addons.mozilla.org a once-over, but nothing grabbed my attention.

I think that, barring an addon, NoScript might be able to help me, but I can't figure out what all the options mean and so don't know what to try.

Comment: You can probably accomplish what you want using AdBlock Plus.

Comment: Could you please explain how you would do this with AdBlock Plus?

Comment: You could [write a filter](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters) that blocks out those filetypes for all domains.

Comment: @Breakthrough, that wouldn't let him activate the plugins with a click the way FlashBlock does.

Comment: @CarlF no, but you could just click the AdBlock Plus button at the top of the browser, and it will show you all media files it blocked (and give you the ability to enable ones).  You can also disable the plugin entirely on certain websites.

Comment: @Breakthrough, I already run AdBlock to block (very annoying) ads. While this solution isn't /exactly/ what I wanted, if nothing else is suggested it will work nicely if I can choose to enable only specific items. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go the hardcore way, you will need the [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/)-Plugin, which blocks JavaScript, XSS and other malicious stuff, unless website explicitly allowed.

As a side effect, websites that completely rely on javascript won't work properly, which is generally not an issue, because most annoying Flash/Quicktime/Java content is linked from other domains.

Comment: I'm just looking to block mainly the QuickTime plugin so it doesn't automatically blare music out when I don't want it to (with a side focus on other plugins, since I don't really have a hankering to run them without my permission either). I don't need all the other stuff that NoScript offers. Can I do that with NoScript?

Comment: I figured it out—NoScript's default options are good, combined with the "Apply these restrictions to whitelisted sites too" option under "Embeddings". This option was what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you want, but you might try [Toolbar Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toolbar-buttons/) - it adds a huge number of buttons available for your toolbars, which on click can stop JavaScript, Java, Flash, animated GIFs etc.

The drawback is that it stops the plugin completely, so if you have lots of tabs opened, it will hurt all of them (for example, when you have a couple of YouTube tabs with videos buffered, and you click "Kill Flash", it will kill all instances, and you will have to reload all those tabs).

By the way: In comments it is said there's something with compatibility with Firefox 6.0 - can't refer, because I use older version still.